# How to disable all OS broadcasts on network interface on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking

I have an Ethernet interface on Windows 10 machine dedicated to testing and I'd like to make it absolutely free from all OS related traffic like MDNS, MBNS, LLMNR etc.

How can I disable all these "unnecessary" OS broadcasts on a single interface while allowing everything coming from regular TCP/UDP applications?

Comment: Here is an article talking about [Limiting or Removing Unwanted Network Traffic at the Client](https://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/3576), kindly check if it was helpful to you.

Comment: @Sunny The article explains how to disable each protocol separately. I was hoping for kind of "kill-all" solution, for example on Linux I used to put an interface under network namespace to keep it isolated from non-relevant protocols and routing. I'm looking for a proper way to do it on Windows.